# Uglify subtask in grunt not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Can't make working subtask in my gruntfile. My task:

```
uglify: {
  foo: {
    options: {             
    },
    dist: {
      files: {
        'test.min.js': [
            "test.js",
            "test2.js"
         ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Grunt log in console:

> Running "uglify:foo" (uglify) task
>
> Done, without errors

But not create file test.min.js. And everything working if I comment foo string subtask like `//foo: {`and `//}`
How I can run subtasks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task config is wrong. It should be:

```
uglify: {
  foo: {
    options: {             
    },
    files: {
      'test.min.js': [
          "test.js",
          "test2.js"
       ]
    }
  }
}
```